# Gradient of the output in tensorflow w.r.t hidden layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

In tensorflow, I am trying to calculate the gradient of the output of a n-layer NN model *denoted as output*  with respect to the hidden layer *denoted as layer_out* for any layer i with i = 1,2,...,n.

The shape of output is [128,10] and the shape of layer_out is [128,100], where 128 is the batch size. I use the following command for this purpose.

```
l_grad = tf.gradients(output, layer_out)[0]
```

The shape of the gradient I expect is [10,100] or [100, 10]. Assuming that the gradient is averaged across the batch. However, the shape I get is [128,100]

One avenue I tried is to use tf.reduce_mean() to average the two quantities across the batches prior to gradient calculation. However, the result is a None list with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_Gen_Error_MNIST_EDL.py", line 128, in <module>
    Results[i,4], Results[i,5], Results[i,6] = Analyse_custom_Optimizer_EDL_old(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test, Kappa_s[i])
  File "Test_Gen_Error_MNIST_EDL.py", line 60, in Analyse_custom_Optimizer_EDL_old
    model = model.init_NN_custom(classes, 1e-03, depth, tf.sigmoid,'EDL')
  File "/usr/local/home/krm9c/Documents/Research/ErrorDriven-Learning/MN/Class_gen_Error.py", line 265, in init_NN_custom
    Error_Loss, self.classifier['class'], array, dec)
  File "/usr/local/home/krm9c/Documents/Research/ErrorDriven-Learning/MN/Class_gen_Error.py", line 192, in direct_feedback_alignement
    print_grad_shape = tf.Print(l_grad, [tf.shape(l_grad)], 'L_gradient shape')
  File "/usr/local/home/krm9c/anaconda2/envs/deep/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 276, in shape
    return shape_internal(input, name, optimize=True, out_type=out_type)
  File "/usr/local/home/krm9c/anaconda2/envs/deep/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 300, in shape_internal
    input_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(input)
  File "/usr/local/home/krm9c/anaconda2/envs/deep/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 932, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/usr/local/home/krm9c/anaconda2/envs/deep/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1022, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/home/krm9c/anaconda2/envs/deep/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 233, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/home/krm9c/anaconda2/envs/deep/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 212, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/home/krm9c/anaconda2/envs/deep/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 401, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

I am missing something here and am not able to figure it out. Any direction is greatly appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: 1. Mathematically, if `f` is size `M`, `x` is size `N`, then the gradient `df/dx` is size `M-by-N`;  in your case, `M=1280, N=12800`; 2. TensorFlow sums up `df/dx` across rows to get a vector the same shape as `x` so that you could possibly use the gradient to update `x`; 3. The graph in Tensorflow is directed. Since `mean(x)` is not used to calculate `mean(f)`, they have no connections and thus the gradient is `None`.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I get now why the gradient is None.  Do you by any chance have an inkling how I can get the gradients in tensorflow averaging across the batches ?

Comment: From what I understand, you were trying to estimate the expectation of the Jacobian matrix. It may not make sense as for a deep NN Jacobian could change everywhere and the mean of matrices may lose much info of each matrix. However, for research purposes, please go ahead. A way is to try `f_list = tf.split(f, 10, axis=1)`, `jaco_vec = [tf.reduce_mean(tf.gradients(f, x)[0], axis=0, keepdims=True) for f in f_list]` and `jacobian = tf.concat(jaco_vec, axis=0)`.

Comment: Richard, Thank You very much for your answer, I am trying to calculate the expectation of the Jacobian for research purposes and your codes gave me just what I needed to get my output.